# Failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: is a directory

Tags: 18.04, docker

**Ubuntu 18.04**

*Kernel 4.15.0-39-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux*

What i'm trying to archive, is to get docker to open a TCP socket on IP 192.168.2.11.

### So i edit the docker configs:

```
systemctl edit docker
```

[image: Image of terminal]
*This is how my /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/.#override.conf looks lik*e.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://192.168.2.11:2375
```

### Then I run:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

I get the following error:

```
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 15 09:45:35 docker systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Nov 15 09:45:35 docker dockerd[27753]: Failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: is a directory
Nov 15 09:45:35 docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 09:45:35 docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 15 09:45:35 docker systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Answer (score 4):

I spend about one hour trying to figure out why, and this is totally my own mistake for not reading the error message. the error message clearly states

**can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: is a directory**

the first thing i do, is to enter root. *(this is how i prefer to not do this, if you dont like to work this way. just add **sudo** infront of all the commmands )*

```
sudo su
```

I check the path, using the following command.

```
ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
```

It shows that, the path is in fact a **directory**. So i delete the directory

```
rm -fr /var/run/docker.sock
```

then i restart the docker.service

```
systemctl edit docker
```

Docker starts, and the output of systemctl status docker is all good.

Conclution: if you get this error message, and run ls on docker.sock and it does not look like this. then remove the directory and restart docker.

```
ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Nov 15 09:47 /var/run/docker.sock
```